# Docker container won't display in browser

Tags: docker-toolbox

I'm using Windows 10 Home and Docker Toolbox. I downloaded a webapp image then ran it with:

> docker run -p 8888:80 aspnetapp

and tried to access it through the browser with

> localhost:8888

but it wouldn't display, said "can't reach this page"

Also, tried the suggestion to get the ip with "docker-machine ip default" and use that instead of localhost

> 192.168.99.100:8888

Still doesn't work. Although, others say these things worked for them. Anyone with any other ideas?

Comment: It works now. Using 192.168.99.100:8888. And for some reason, it does not work in Internet Explorer, but when I tried it in Chrome, it worked.